# How do I read a time value and then insert it into a TimeSpan variable

Tags: c#, .net, time, timespan

How do I read a time value and then insert it into a TimeSpan variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you're trying to get some user input in the form of "08:00" and want to store the time in a timespan variable?

So.. something like this?

```
string input = "08:00";
DateTime time;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(input, out time))
{
    // invalid input
    return;
}

TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second);
```

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx): A TimeSpan object represents a time interval, or duration of time, measured as a positive or negative number of days, hours, minutes, seconds, and fractions of a second. The largest unit of time used to measure duration is a day.

Here's how you can initialize it to CurrentTime (in ticks):

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(days,hours,minutes,seconds,milliseonds);
```

Or, if you mean DateTime:

```
DateTime time = new DateTime(year,month,day,minutes,seconds,milliseconds);
```

Where all of the parameters are ints.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using:

```
var span = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);
```

If you mean adding two timespans together use:

```
var newSpan = span.Add(new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds));
```

For more information see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the properties of a TimeSpan. You need to create a new instance and pass the new values there.

Comment: the other posts have already said it: yourObject.TimeSpan = new TimeSpan(hours, mins, secs);